# как прочесть цифру из файла xml?

Tags: c#, xml

Добрый вечер плохо разбираюсь в xml но мне надо.

```
    <global>
     <level-1>
<gamer name="ilya"/>
<score id="1" />
</level-1>
</global>
```

Пример с верху. 
итак мне надо прочесть цифру 1 которая находится в id с помощью C#
и  записать в переменную `z`
Как это можно реализовать бьюсь уже час но все равно не знаю.

Comment: эм... использовать любой `xml-парсер` в `C#` даже встроенный где-то был.

Comment: а можно примерчик?

Comment: в принципе легкая задача. задача вообще не чем но блин такой я ничего не понял

Comment: А что считается фиксированным?

Comment: Непонял????????

Comment: Блин вместо того чтобы критиковать и ставить - могли-бы уже помочь !!!

Comment: @ильявитюк а вам что-то "должны" ? Я сейчас попробую накидать, но скорее всего - что-то вы делаете не так, раз у вас возникает такая проблема.

Comment: @Monk  мне никто ничего не должен но все-таки можно и помочь т.к. не считаю правильно так делать

Comment: Начнём с того, что у вас невалидный XML. `<gamer name="ilya">` нигде не закрывается.

Comment: да забыл. плохо разбираюсь. спасибо

Comment: @ильявитюк, а в чём конкретно нужно помочь? В чём именно проблема? Что не получается? Ваш код можно увидеть?

Comment: >Блин вместо того чтобы критиковать и ставить - могли-бы уже помочь !!! -- а вы могли бы ответить на вопросы тех, у кого вы просите совета.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  var doc = XDocument.Load("person.xml");
  var score = doc.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == "score");
  var id = score.Attributes().Single(a => a.Name == "id").Value;
```

Загрузка файла, поиск элемента, который назван `score` и чтение из него аттрибута, с названием `id`. В текущем виде, полученный `id` - строка, какого типа у вас `z` вы не указали, так что в целом - задача решена.

Посмотрел ваши вопросы - судя по всему, вы хотите работать с игровой статистикой.

### Так вот, выше приведенный код очень неудобен для этого.

Что бы я примерно предложил. Во первых, вспомогательный код, для работы с xml:

```
  class Serializer<T>
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Сохранить в файл.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Save(string path, T data)
    {
      var formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
      using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
        formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Загрузить из файла.
    /// </summary>
    public static T Load(string path)
    {
      var type = typeof(T);
      T retVal;
      var formatter = new XmlSerializer(type);
      try
      {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
          retVal = (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
      }
      catch (System.Exception)
      {
        return default(T);
      }
      return retVal;
    }
  }
```

Теперь, используя этот класс, можно легко написать вот такие классы для статистики:

```
  public class PlayerStatistic
  {
    public string Player { get; set; }

    public int Score { get; set; }

    public string LevelName { get; set; }

    public int LevelId { get; set; }
  }

  public class GameStatistic
  {
    private static readonly string XmlFile = "GameStatistic.xml";

    public List<PlayerStatistic> PlayerStatistics { get; set; }

    public void Save()
    {
      Serializer<GameStatistic>.Save(XmlFile, this);
    }

    public static GameStatistic Load()
    {
      return Serializer<GameStatistic>.Load(XmlFile) ?? new GameStatistic();
    }

    private GameStatistic()
    {
      this.PlayerStatistics = new List<PlayerStatistic>();
    }
  }
```

Ну и, как этим пользоваться в игре:

```
  var gameStat = GameStatistic.Load();
  foreach (var statistic in gameStat.PlayerStatistics)
  {
    // делаете что хотите с каждой записью statistic.
  }

  // Добавление новой записи
  var newResult = new PlayerStatistic();
  newResult.Player = "Me!";
  newResult.Score = 123;
  newResult.LevelName = "Tutorial";
  newResult.LevelId = 1;
  gameStat.PlayerStatistics.Add(newResult);

  // Не забываем сохранять статистику в файл.
  gameStat.Save();
```

Класс `GameStatistic` в текущей реализации лучше загружать только один, чтобы не терять статистику. Обычно для этого используется паттерн "одиночка", можете погуглить, если станет нужно.

Вот так выглядит в итоге xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GameStatistic xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <PlayerStatistics>
    <PlayerStatistic>
      <Player>Me!</Player>
      <Score>123</Score>
      <LevelName>Tutorial</LevelName>
      <LevelId>1</LevelId>
    </PlayerStatistic>
    <PlayerStatistic>
      <Player>Me!</Player>
      <Score>222</Score>
      <LevelName>First Step</LevelName>
      <LevelId>2</LevelId>
    </PlayerStatistic>
  </PlayerStatistics>
</GameStatistic>
```

Главное, что для вас важно - заранее определить, что будет в статистике. Я, посмотрев на ваш xml - закинул туда игрока, счет, название уровня и какой-то потенциальный id уровня, название - чтобы отображать, а id - чтобы можно было однозначно группировать данные, мало ли, уровни переименуются.

ПС: в целом, код поддерживает спокойное добавление свойств как в `PlayerStatistic` так и в `GameStatistic`.

Comment: "Посмотрел ваши вопросы - судя по всему, вы хотите ..." - вот это желание помочь! Уважаю. @ильявитюк - цените.